# Looking for a method to increment a Modbus register address by two in XML code

Tags: xml

I am working with an XML export from a framework that uses Modbus. I need to increment the Modbus register address value of each data point by two without having to input it directly. I am tranlating this data from other formats to Modbus to be read outside of the system. There is not a method to auto generated the register values. Is there a good method to perform this task? I am not sure if regex or a python script would work better to accomplish this task.

Here is a partial extract of the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bajaObjectGraph version="4.0" reversibleEncodingKeySource="none" FIPSEnabled="false" reversibleEncodingValidator="[null.1]=" >
<p m="b=baja" t="b:UnrestrictedFolder">
 <p n="DHC3_PCT1A1_Voltage_Module" h="1" m="mc=modbusCore" t="mc:ModbusServerPointFolder">
  <p n="System_Voltage_LL" h="2" m="c=control" t="c:NumericWritable">
   <p n="facets" t="b:Facets" v="units=u:volt;V;(m2)(kg)(s-3)(A-1);;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf"/>
   <p n="proxyExt" h="3" t="mc:ModbusServerNumericProxyExt">
    <p n="deviceFacets" t="b:Facets" v="units=u:null;;;;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf"/>
    <p n="dataAddress" t="mc:FlexAddress">
     <p n="addressFormat" t="mc:AddressFormatEnum" v="modbus"/>
     <p n="address" v="31656"/>
    </p>
    <p n="regType" t="mc:RegisterTypeEnum" v="input"/>
    <p n="dataType" t="mc:DataTypeEnum" v="floatType"/>
   </p>
   <p n="fallback" f="L"/>
  </p>
  <p n="System_Voltage_LN" h="4" t="c:NumericWritable">
   <p n="facets" t="b:Facets" v="units=u:volt;V;(m2)(kg)(s-3)(A-1);;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf"/>
   <p n="proxyExt" h="5" t="mc:ModbusServerNumericProxyExt">
    <p n="deviceFacets" t="b:Facets" v="units=u:null;;;;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf"/>
    <p n="dataAddress" t="mc:FlexAddress">
     <p n="addressFormat" t="mc:AddressFormatEnum" v="modbus"/>
     <p n="address" v="31658"/>
    </p>
    <p n="regType" t="mc:RegisterTypeEnum" v="input"/>
    <p n="dataType" t="mc:DataTypeEnum" v="floatType"/>
   </p>
   <p n="fallback" f="L"/>
  </p>
  <p n="Frequency" h="6" t="c:NumericWritable">
   <p n="facets" t="b:Facets" v="units=u:hertz;Hz;(s-1);;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf"/>
   <p n="proxyExt" h="7" t="mc:ModbusServerNumericProxyExt">
    <p n="deviceFacets" t="b:Facets" v="units=u:null;;;;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf"/>
    <p n="dataAddress" t="mc:FlexAddress">
     <p n="addressFormat" t="mc:AddressFormatEnum" v="modbus"/>
     <p n="address" v="31660"/>
    </p>
    <p n="regType" t="mc:RegisterTypeEnum" v="input"/>
    <p n="dataType" t="mc:DataTypeEnum" v="floatType"/>
   </p>
   <p n="fallback" f="L"/>
  </p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `python` one option might be:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

src_xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bajaObjectGraph version="4.0" reversibleEncodingKeySource="none" FIPSEnabled="false" reversibleEncodingValidator="[null.1]=">
    <p m="b=baja" t="b:UnrestrictedFolder">
        <p n="DHC3_PCT1A1_Voltage_Module" h="1" m="mc=modbusCore" t="mc:ModbusServerPointFolder">
            <p n="System_Voltage_LL" h="2" m="c=control" t="c:NumericWritable">
                <p n="facets" t="b:Facets" v="units=u:volt;V;(m2)(kg)(s-3)(A-1);;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf"/>
                <p n="proxyExt" h="3" t="mc:ModbusServerNumericProxyExt">
                    <p n="deviceFacets" t="b:Facets" v="units=u:null;;;;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf"/>
                    <p n="dataAddress" t="mc:FlexAddress">
                        <p n="addressFormat" t="mc:AddressFormatEnum" v="modbus"/>
                        <p n="address" v="31656"/>
                    </p>
                    <p n="regType" t="mc:RegisterTypeEnum" v="input"/>
                    <p n="dataType" t="mc:DataTypeEnum" v="floatType"/>
                </p>
                <p n="fallback" f="L"/>
            </p>
            <p n="System_Voltage_LN" h="4" t="c:NumericWritable">
                <p n="facets" t="b:Facets" v="units=u:volt;V;(m2)(kg)(s-3)(A-1);;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf"/>
                <p n="proxyExt" h="5" t="mc:ModbusServerNumericProxyExt">
                    <p n="deviceFacets" t="b:Facets" v="units=u:null;;;;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf"/>
                    <p n="dataAddress" t="mc:FlexAddress">
                        <p n="addressFormat" t="mc:AddressFormatEnum" v="modbus"/>
                        <p n="address" v="31658"/>
                    </p>
                    <p n="regType" t="mc:RegisterTypeEnum" v="input"/>
                    <p n="dataType" t="mc:DataTypeEnum" v="floatType"/>
                </p>
                <p n="fallback" f="L"/>
            </p>
            <p n="Frequency" h="6" t="c:NumericWritable">
                <p n="facets" t="b:Facets" v="units=u:hertz;Hz;(s-1);;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf"/>
                <p n="proxyExt" h="7" t="mc:ModbusServerNumericProxyExt">
                    <p n="deviceFacets" t="b:Facets" v="units=u:null;;;;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf"/>
                    <p n="dataAddress" t="mc:FlexAddress">
                        <p n="addressFormat" t="mc:AddressFormatEnum" v="modbus"/>
                        <p n="address" v="31660"/>
                    </p>
                    <p n="regType" t="mc:RegisterTypeEnum" v="input"/>
                    <p n="dataType" t="mc:DataTypeEnum" v="floatType"/>
                </p>
                <p n="fallback" f="L"/>
            </p>
        </p>
    </p>
</bajaObjectGraph>'''

tree = ET.fromstring(src_xml)
for node in tree.findall('.//p'):
    if 'n' in node.attrib and node.attrib['n']=="address":
        node.attrib['v'] = str(int(node.attrib['v'])+2)

print(ET.tostring(tree).decode())
```

Output:

```
<bajaObjectGraph version="4.0" reversibleEncodingKeySource="none" FIPSEnabled="false" reversibleEncodingValidator="[null.1]=">
    <p m="b=baja" t="b:UnrestrictedFolder">
        <p n="DHC3_PCT1A1_Voltage_Module" h="1" m="mc=modbusCore" t="mc:ModbusServerPointFolder">
            <p n="System_Voltage_LL" h="2" m="c=control" t="c:NumericWritable">
                <p n="facets" t="b:Facets" v="units=u:volt;V;(m2)(kg)(s-3)(A-1);;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf" />
                <p n="proxyExt" h="3" t="mc:ModbusServerNumericProxyExt">
                    <p n="deviceFacets" t="b:Facets" v="units=u:null;;;;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf" />
                    <p n="dataAddress" t="mc:FlexAddress">
                        <p n="addressFormat" t="mc:AddressFormatEnum" v="modbus" />
                        <p n="address" v="31658" />
                    </p>
                    <p n="regType" t="mc:RegisterTypeEnum" v="input" />
                    <p n="dataType" t="mc:DataTypeEnum" v="floatType" />
                </p>
                <p n="fallback" f="L" />
            </p>
            <p n="System_Voltage_LN" h="4" t="c:NumericWritable">
                <p n="facets" t="b:Facets" v="units=u:volt;V;(m2)(kg)(s-3)(A-1);;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf" />
                <p n="proxyExt" h="5" t="mc:ModbusServerNumericProxyExt">
                    <p n="deviceFacets" t="b:Facets" v="units=u:null;;;;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf" />
                    <p n="dataAddress" t="mc:FlexAddress">
                        <p n="addressFormat" t="mc:AddressFormatEnum" v="modbus" />
                        <p n="address" v="31660" />
                    </p>
                    <p n="regType" t="mc:RegisterTypeEnum" v="input" />
                    <p n="dataType" t="mc:DataTypeEnum" v="floatType" />
                </p>
                <p n="fallback" f="L" />
            </p>
            <p n="Frequency" h="6" t="c:NumericWritable">
                <p n="facets" t="b:Facets" v="units=u:hertz;Hz;(s-1);;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf" />
                <p n="proxyExt" h="7" t="mc:ModbusServerNumericProxyExt">
                    <p n="deviceFacets" t="b:Facets" v="units=u:null;;;;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf" />
                    <p n="dataAddress" t="mc:FlexAddress">
                        <p n="addressFormat" t="mc:AddressFormatEnum" v="modbus" />
                        <p n="address" v="31662" />
                    </p>
                    <p n="regType" t="mc:RegisterTypeEnum" v="input" />
                    <p n="dataType" t="mc:DataTypeEnum" v="floatType" />
                </p>
                <p n="fallback" f="L" />
            </p>
        </p>
    </p>
</bajaObjectGraph>
```